# React passing a variable to component as a prop

Tags: reactjs

If I have a component like `<MyComponent isRed/>`, is there a way to replace the `isRed` prop with a variable so that I can pass `<MyComponent isBlue />` or `<MyComponent isGreen />` conditionally with the same component?

If I did `<MyComponent color={isColor}/>` I would still need to determine what `color` is at `MyComponent`

I know I can achieve what I'm looking for by making a switch and return `<MyComponent isRed/>`, `<MyComponent isBlue/>` and `<MyComponent isGreen/>` depending on the case but that's a lot of redundant code so I was wondering if there's a way to do something like `<MyComponent {isColor}/>`?

Comment: Make `color` a string prop?
`<MyComponent color="red"`
`<MyComponent color="blue"`
`<MyComponent color="green"`
Or if it even more general perhaps allow:
`<MyComponent color="rgba(255,121,199,0.4)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could give some more context about what it is you're trying to do?
As I'm not entirely sure what your question is about, but I will try my best to answer.

**If you need to actually set the color of something:**
Let's say you're trying to set a background color of some element. You can just pass a string to the component to use it there:

```js
let color = "#FF0000";
<YourComponent color={color} />
```

Using this approach you could directly use this string with the color value and use it to modify the color of your component:

```js
const YourComponentReceivingTheColor = ({color}) => {
   return <div style={{ backgroundColor: color }} />
}
```